# How to verify PayPal Express Checkout details on the server?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm just now trying to get up to speed with PayPal Express Checkout (i.e. checkout.js), using the client-side REST integration described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/).  I see that when payment is complete, my onAuthorize function is invoked with a "payment" object.

I can't find any documentation on this object, but some poking at it reveals the following properties (at least today):

- paymentToken
- payerID
- paymentID
- intent
- returnUrl

Now I need to redirect the user to the next step on my website, where I show a receipt confirming they've paid, etc.  I guess I send the above data to the server, but since that step could be easily spoofed by a malicious user, I will need to verify those details in the PHP code, server side.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a `GET` call on your server side to `/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXXX` with the `paymentID` and the `payerID` to get the payment details, and verify those details there.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/show-payment-details/

See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#make-your-first-call for some basics on calling the REST api from your server

Comment: Sounds like just what I need.  I'll mark this as the accepted answer as soon as I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: Confirmed, works like a charm!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: hey @JoeStrout can you post an example of the call that you made? I have the same exact situation. the documentation is horribly confusing.

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using **[PayPal Encrypted Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/)**, you don't actually **need** to verify the amounts sent through server-side. Although a user could indeed manipulate the `$_POST` data, PayPal's got you covered, and won't allow the transaction to go through. This is because PayPal Encrypted Buttons are generated with your variables such as price built-in to the ID. If the variables don't align with those used to create the button, the transaction is denied.

Alternatively, if you are simply using your own code to make the request, you can secure the payments with PayPal's **[Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)**. Again, this allows *any* `$_POST` data to be sent through for the payment. Afterwards, PayPal makes a call to your IPN page in order to validate that the parameters are correct. This is demonstrated in the following workflow:

[image: IPN Flow]

When communicating with your IPN, if PayPal finds that the values don't match up, the order is cancelled. Assuming that the values match up, you can safely redirect them to your confirmation page.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think I've been unclear.  I'm not using the "classic" API; I'm using the _new_ Express Checkout with client-side integration provided by checkout.js (version 4), as described here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/  Unless I'm even more confused than I think I am, I don't believe the above advice applies in this case.